# Entity Framework connection not recognizing Temp Table created

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4, temp-tables

I've got a process that takes records from a daily feed in an Access database and adds the records to a sql server.

The load occationally fails, so I'm trying to add via a SQL server Global Temp Table and then a much quicker Delete/Insert from that temp table.

I've got the following code that works in TSQL:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'tempdb.dbo.####TempCountry' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##TempCountry; 
SELECT * INTO ##TempCountry  FROM dbo.Country WHERE 1 = 2;
INSERT INTO ##TempCountry (CountryCode, CountryName) VALUES ('AF','AFGHANISTAN')
SELECT * FROM  ##TempCountry
```

And I've translated this to `ExecuteStoreCommand`'s using an EntityFramework connection:

```
using (MyEntities _ent = new MyEntities ()) {
  //Create a temp table
  try {
    _ent.ExecuteStoreCommand("IF OBJECT_ID ( 'tempdb.dbo.##TempCountry' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##TempCountry");
    _ent.ExecuteStoreCommand("SELECT * INTO ##TempCountry FROM dbo.Country  WHERE 1 = 2");
    _ent.ExecuteStoreCommand("INSERT INTO ##TempCountry (CountryCode, CountryName, RegionCode) VALUES ('AF','AFGHANISTAN')");
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    //Generic error 
    Console.writeline("  Unknown error inserting Country: {0} - {1} ", sCountryCode, ex.Message);
  }
} //EF
```

When I hit the final `ExecuteStoreCommand`, the code throws a SqlException:  "Invalid object name '##TempCountry'."

But I can see the table when I execute a "Select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `ExecuteStoreCommand` will execute on a different sessions. The table will be dropped as soon as the first command finishes executing.

From MSDN - [CREATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) (under the Remarks section, in Temporary Tables):

> Global temporary tables are automatically dropped when the session that created the table ends and all other tasks have stopped referencing them.

One solution is to execute all of the commands in one SQL batch, not separate commands.

Comment: So basically, there's no way to do any work with ExecuteStoreCommand and temp tables in a loop...

Comment: @Christopher_G_Lewis - If you execute all of the different SQL commands in one `ExecuteStoreCommand`, I believe you will be OK. Try it.

Comment: Yes, but the idea of this was to read in from an Access database and insert into a SQL temp table, verify it and write it out to the final SQL table.

Comment: @Christopher_G_Lewis - Perhaps using a stored procedure and passing in a [table valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) would be a better solution.